# expire_on_close en Chrome no funciona (Forzar cerrar sesión)

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, ajax

Tengo un problema que estoy seguro que a alguien más le habrá pasado alguna vez. Es muy sencillo, he hecho login en mi proyecto (un proyecto de PHP con Laravel) y, cuando cierro Chrome y lo vuelvo a abrir, la sesión sigue abierta.

Tengo configurado que mantenga las pestañas abiertas cuando cierre el navegador y no hago ninguna pregunta indicando si quiere mantener la sesión abierta.

En mi fichero config/session.php tengo:

```
lifetime = 720;

expire_on_close = true;
```

En Firefox funciona perfectamente, así que pongo la mano en el fuego que el problema está en Chrome.

Como solución así de urgencia he intentado capturar el evento "beforeunload" y hacer una llamada Ajax hacia una función del Controller para indicar que haga el Logout del usuario (`Auth::logout()`), pero debugando en esa función veo que no pasa (Entiendo que ya no le da tiempo a pasar).

**Script**

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function ()
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        url: '{{url('/')}}/forceLogout'
    });
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('forceLogout', ['uses' => 'LoginController@forceLogout', 'as' => 'forceLogout']);
```

**LoginController**

```
public static function forceLogout()
{
    Auth::logout();
}
```

Por lo tanto, existe alguna solución?

Comment: Tal vez no sea lo que buscas, pero, puede funcionar, si la duración de sesión sin actividad se controla en la base de datos, y hay un cron que mata las sesiones inactivas cada cierto tiempo, cuando se recarguen las pestañas, (chrome lo hará desde caché) la sesión no está activa y al actuar dentro de la página las credenciales no serán válidas y user tendrá que relogearse.

Comment: Pufffff, intentaría evitar el uso de la BBDD pudiendo hacer las cosas directamente con herramientas del propio navegador. Ha de haber algo. He estado buscando y el problema está detectado en Chrome desde 2012...

Comment: Si lo encuentras te agradecería mucho que lo **resaltes** hace tiempo que decidí dejar de luchar con el caché de los navegadores... siempre ofrecen cosas inesperadas

Comment: Si, no te preocupes. Si encuentro la solución comentaré para que estés pendiente ;)